# ZFS of whole disks with ashift=12 vs of aliagned partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, zfs

About to create zpool made of 14 hdd disks, and I see options:

- can simple do `zpool create -f -o ashift=12 DATA raidz2 disk1 disk2 ...`

or

- can use eg `parted` to create one partition on each drive optimally aligned and then do `zpool create -f -o ashift=12 DATA raidz2 disk1-part1 disk2-part2 ...`

In both cases data to be aligned optimally, but which approach is more (so to say) ZFS-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter either way, but there are some things to be aware of:

- With whole-disks:

  - You remove (or reduce) the potential for alignment issues
  - You remove the offset calculations to access a partition (which are admittedly negligible)
  - I've seen people suggesting "*it's better, it just is*" or arguing about better disk cache usage and other things, but with little to back it up....
  - Some systems (e.g: Windows) might not know how to deal with the disk and present it as "*Uninitialized*", which may lead to confusion or data loss
- With partitions:

  - You may be more likely to run into alignment issues
  - You can include other data on the disks, e.g: `/boot` or a small FAT filesystem to identify the disk (if it's an external / grab disk)
  - You can reduce the partition size slightly (e.g: by leaving ~100 MB unallocated at the end of the disk) to account for the varying size that an "*x TB*" disk will actually present as, meaning that a replacement disk of the "*same size*" might be more likely to fit the "*equal or greater than*" requirements

As far as I can see, the only real benefits come from using partitions - namely alleviating concerns about replacement disks being "*only just too small*" for use, and permitting other small amounts of data to be kept on the disk (i.e: `/boot` or identification).

I have taken both approaches, and in use there is really no noticible difference (though admittedly without extensive A/B testing).

---

Bear in mind that (on Linux at least), "*whole-disk*" setup will actually create a GPT partition table on your behalf, with an ~8MiB partition at the end of the disk with the "*Solaris reserved*" type (to address the size variations mentioned above). It will also set the `whole_disk` field to `true` (see `zdb -l ${pool}`).

Read more: [OpenZFS - Whole Disks versus Partitions](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Performance%20and%20Tuning/Workload%20Tuning.html#whole-disks-versus-partitions)

---

Something else to consider is that a 14-disk vdev is quite large - you might prefer to break this up into two or more vdevs. It largely depends on the size of the disks, redundancy level, and the associated rebuild time... ***plan*** for it, don't ***hope*** that it won't happen.

---

```bash
truncate -s 1G a b c d e f g h i
zpool create TEST raidz2 ${PWD}/a ${PWD}/b ${PWD}/c ${PWD}/d raidz2 ${PWD}/e ${PWD}/f ${PWD}/g ${PWD}/h
zpool add TEST log ${PWD}/i
zpool status TEST
```

```
  pool: TEST
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        TEST                       ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/a  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/b  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/c  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/d  ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-1                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/e  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/f  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/g  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /home/attie/box/tmp/h  ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          /home/attie/box/tmp/i    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

```bash
zpool destroy TEST
rm a b c d e f g h i
```

Comment: My problem is that I have only 14 HDD and 2 SSD attached and want to have some fault-tolerant setup. Raidz2 appears to be nice idea and looks like I'd should go with 2 x 7-disks raidz2 instead on 1 x 14-disks raidz2 (2x7 will be better as of IOPs), but then I have too few SSDs to use it as ZIL (should be mirror) and L2ARC.

Comment: Do you need a ZIL? Do you need L2ARC? You need to seriously consider your workload.

Comment: ZIL and cache are assigned to the top-level vdev, not the sub vdevs... I'll add an example. Don't forget, you can also partition your SSDs... Do you really need to dedicate a whole device for ZIL/Cache?